# Macro definition conflict

Tags: c++, macros

I'm running into this issue. This is not about macro functions, just simple string-value macro replacement.

I have two header files

```
test1.h
#define TEST 123
test2.h
#define TEST 456
```

Now I have a program included  both these two headers, but I want my actually TEST to be 123.
How can I avoid defining TEST as 456?

You might think I'm crazy not to simply change the macro, but the situation is: I have a third-party decoder, which has this macro (defined in test1.h), and there's another WINAPI macro (defined in test2.h). Both of these files are controlled by others; I should not change either of them.
I don't need the test2.h at all, but I guess it's implicitly included by some other WINAPI header.

So, could anyone please tell me how to work around this issue? To overwrite the WINAPI macro with my third-party macro? Or how to nullify the definition from the WINAPI header in my own code? Is there a way to specify which header I don't want to include.

Comment: You could just redefine it in your code, after the includes. That would re-define it yet again so that it would have the correct value everywhere it needed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `#ifdef` pre-processor directive to determine if `TEST` is defined already for your particular case. Or just `#undef` it first.

```
#undef TEST
#define TEST 123
```

Put that in your header file where you want `TEST` to be 123 and not 456. Also, this needs to be before `test1.h`.

Comment: No: `#undef TEST` and `#define TEST 123` are sufficient.

Comment: it works! Thankyou! I didnt know there's a #undef, now I got it.

Answer (score 2):

`#undef TEST` after the include of `test2.h` and before the include of `test1.h`. This is a bit of a hack though since you can't fix the macro names.

Answer (score 2):

You can undefine it if you include both headers to your file as:

```
//yourfile.cpp

#include "test2.h"  //include this before test1.h

#undef TEST   //this undefines the macro defined in test2.h 

#include "test1.h"  //now this defines a macro called TEST which you need
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#ifdef TEST
#undef TEST
#define TEST 123
#endif
```

Comment: No: `#undef TEST` and `#define TEST 123` are sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include "test2.h"
#undef TEST
#include "test1.h"
```

This first includes test2, discards its `TEST` and then includes test1.