# C/C++ macro conflict from external libraries

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to combine boost/asio library with ncurses, but they have macro conflict. It gives this error message:

```
[build] /usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_socket_streambuf.hpp:640:39: error: expected expression
[build]             socket().native_handle(), timeout(), ec_) < 0)
[build]                                       ^
[build] /usr/include/curses.h:1245:47: note: expanded from macro 'timeout'
[build] #define timeout(delay)          wtimeout(stdscr,(delay))
[build]
```

To be precise, I have a ui.hpp file and it is later included in main code. ui.hpp includes <ncurses.h> and then defines classes. One of the classes declares variables that are from <ncurses.h> header so I can't move #include <ncurses.h> from ui.hpp file to ui.cpp (unless there is a workaround):

```
class BorderedWindow {
protected:
    // I need #include <ncurses> to declare these 2 vars
    WINDOW *window_;
    WINDOW *border_;
```

Should I compile ui in a static library separately and then link it to main application, or is there an easier way of doing it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Macro definition conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109795/macro-definition-conflict)

Comment: @Marvin no, I can't undef conflicting macro

Comment: The obvious approach is to use wrapper functions to avoid need to include headers from both ncurses and boost/asio simultaneously in any header or source file.    In other words, avoid having any source file or header that simultaneously uses types functions from both libraries.

Comment: @Peter yeah, I figured it out, but as I said, I cannot exclude 2 variable definitions in ui.hpp without big changes to code.

Comment: @Peter though now thinking, I can change WINDOW* to void* and then delete #include <ncurses.h> in header file and then the code should work... It's dirty as hell, but it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent a macro conflict you need to redo a structure of your project that way, so no file include both ncurses.h and boost/asio.hpp headers simultaneously. To do this you need to wrap one library in .hpp+.cpp pair and *also* make sure that .hpp doesn't include the header of this library and only .cpp does. Then only use the wrapper instead of the library.

In my case, variable definitions made it harder because I can't use the library types without including header. But I changed all my vars defined in ui.hpp from ncurses.h header to void*, casted all of them to respective types in ui.cpp and deleted #include <ncurses.h> from header and my code compiled. It's not a good solution, but it works.